# Do I need a transit visa for Bangkok going to Don Muang?

Tags: transit-visas, thailand, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan travelling to SGN via Bangkok.

I am travelling on UL flight to Bangkok Suvarnabhumi Airport and my connecting flight to SGN is from Don Mueang Airport.

Do I need a transit visa to enter Bangkok to go to Don Mueang Airport?

Answer (score 3):

TIMATIC states:

> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Bangkok (DMK) arriving on Thai AirAsia (FD) or Thai AirAsia X
>   (XJ) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight on Thai AirAsia (FD) or Thai AirAsia X (XJ) to a third country within
>   12 hours. The connecting flight must be booked on the same ticket. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next
>   destination.

As you leave the transit area to switch airport you will need a visa.